# unknown configuration format: hocon (supported formats are: [json, raw, properties]

Tags: java, vert.x, typesafe-config

I am trying to use the Hocon format for configuration in Vertx. I have also added the maven dependency for it.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-config-hocon</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

The code compiles fine in eclipse.

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions();

ConfigStoreOptions store = new ConfigStoreOptions().setType("file").setFormat("hocon").setConfig(new JsonObject().put("path", System.getProperty("configPath")));

ConfigRetriever retriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx, new ConfigRetrieverOptions().addStore(store));
```

However, when I run the binary and passing a hocon configuration file as a command line argument, I am getting the following unknown configuration exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown configuration format: hocon (supported formats are: [json, raw, properties]
```

I have also checked `io.vertx.config.spi.ConfigProcessor` in the jar file. And I don't find the expected  `io.vertx.config.hocon.HoconProcessor`.

Am I missing some build configuration in POM file? Is there any important thing to be included in the POM file to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The vertx-config formats are configured using a SPI file (`META-INF/services/io.vertx.config.spi.ConfigProcessor` file). Can you check the content of this file in your final jar? To work, it must contain the `io.vertx.config.hocon.HoconProcessor` line. As you are also depending on `vertx-config` (also containing this file), you need to configure the Maven Shader plugin to combine the different files into one. Check https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer for details. The Vert.x Maven Plugin does that automatically (https://github.com/reactiverse/vertx-maven-plugin)

Comment: How does this work if I am using Kotlin, gradle(Kotlin DSL) and trying to build jar with shadow jar?