# How can I get the HOCON configuration file format to work in Vert.x deployed as fat jar?

Tags: vert.x, hocon, fatjar, shadowjar

I want to use the **HOCON** format for configuration in a Vert.x application deployed as a fat jar. I'm facing the same issue as described in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610406/unknown-configuration-format-hocon-supported-formats-are-json-raw-properti).

However I applied the gradle Plugin "io.vertx.vertx-plugin" (v1.0.1) and succeeded in getting the line `io.vertx.config.hocon.HoconProcessor` into  `META-INF/services/io.vertx.config.spi.ConfigProcessor` in the jar.

I still get the exception. What else could be required for the proper bundling of the HoconProcessor class in the jar?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it took quite a while to figure out what the problem was. In my case I was building a fat jar using the gradle shadowJar plugin. To start the application I used the `vertx` command what resulted in the described error. Starting the application directly with java using `java -jar my-fat-jar.jar` was no problem.

So I had a look into the vertx script and found out that the classpath is set like this: `CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:${VERTX_HOME}/conf:${VERTX_HOME}/lib/*` so the fat jar is actually not in the classpath and the ConfigProcessor for YAML can not be found. Using `CLASSPATH=my-fat-jar.jar vertx run my-fat-jar.jar` works properly.

So you can either use this or start you application directly using java as described above.