# Shaddow Jar missing some Vert.x classes from dependecies

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, gradle-kotlin-dsl, shadowjar

I have successfully created a shadow-jar with few verticles using Kotlin coroutines extension and able to run them via `vertx run` command line while specifying the path to my jar except a verticle that on its start-up creates a telnet shell with exception:

```java
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.vertx.ext.shell.term.TelnetTermOptions
    at io.vertx.kotlin.ext.shell.term.TelnetTermOptionsKt.telnetTermOptionsOf(TelnetTermOptions.kt:119)
    at io.vertx.kotlin.ext.shell.term.TelnetTermOptionsKt.telnetTermOptionsOf$default(TelnetTermOptions.kt:119)
    at **********************.ContactsReceiver.start(ContactsReceiver.kt:20)
    at io.vertx.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineVerticle$start$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutineVerticle.kt:53)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:238)
    at io.vertx.kotlin.coroutines.VertxCoroutineExecutor.execute(VertxCoroutine.kt:214)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.ExecutorCoroutineDispatcherBase.dispatch(Executors.kt:64)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedKt.resumeCancellable(Dispatched.kt:413)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:25)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:109)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:154)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:54)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineVerticle.start(CoroutineVerticle.kt:51)
    at io.vertx.core.Verticle.start(Verticle.java:66)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeploy$8(DeploymentManager.java:556)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager$$Lambda$126.0000000063922220.handle(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeTask(ContextImpl.java:369)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$executeAsync$0(EventLoopContext.java:38)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext$$Lambda$127.0000000060DA8B00.run(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:510)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:518)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

My project is built using Gradle (Kotlin DSL)

These are my vert.x dependencies:

```
io.vertx:vertx-core
io.vertx:vertx-lang-kotlin
io.vertx:vertx-lang-kotlin-coroutines
io.vertx:vertx-shell
io.vertx:vertx-auth-shiro
io.vertx:vertx-tcp-eventbus-bridge
```

And my shadow jar task configered like so:

```
tasks.withType<com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar> {
    classifier = "fat"
    isPreserveFileTimestamps = false
    isReproducibleFileOrder = true
    minimize()
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Verticle"] = vertx.mainVerticle
    }
    mergeServiceFiles {
        include("META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory")
    }
}
```

Seems like `minimize()` is not the issue but what is important that if I deploy that verticle programatically from the `main` function evrything works fine and I got the telnet shell.

Perhaps I missing something in my manifest configuration on the shadow jar task?

Comment: I had a similar issue as minimize jar will only include classes that can resolve from tree in compile time. If some classes are called in runtime they might be missing. This is why I have filter that explicitly pack all clases from some of vertx dependencies. Can you double check without minimize jar option and see if it works.

Comment: I’ve tried without `minimize()` with no changes in the outcome. Can you please elaborate more bout jar options and/or your explicit fileter? Perhaps it might help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a remotely similar issues with the HoconProcessor ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974113/how-can-i-get-the-hocon-configuration-file-format-to-work-in-vert-x-deployed-as)), but in the mean time more relevantly, also with the class GraphiQLHandlerOptions, of which I imported a deprecated version ([look](https://github.com/vert-x3/wiki/wiki/3.8.1-Deprecations-and-breaking-changes)), causing the class to be included in the jar under the same name, but its use expectedly throwing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

Since `TelnetTermOptions` is such an options class too, maybe it suffered from a similar deprecation recently. Hope this helps/inspires.